# Jenkins Build from Tag or Master

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a requirement where depending on the interest of the developer, He might want to choose to build from master branch  or Tag.

I was able to build from tags using the Git parameter plugin. From the git parameter plugin, when I choose Tags or branch, I can see my tags and branches. But When I select a branch to build from, I get the following git error.

> +refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/* +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
>   00:00:02.508  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/tags/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   00:00:02.549  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/tags/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   00:00:02.590  > git rev-parse origin/tags/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10

Can someone please help me to achieve the above requirement in one Jenkins Job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:
[image]

Put the desired tag or branch in the CHECKOUT variable. Here you can also filter on all tags and only the master branch if you want (origin/master)
Use this variable as specified branch to checkout from in the git plugin
[image]

Comment: Nope, It Doesnt Work.
You can find the output here
https://jpst.it/1auDW

Comment: Strange, difficult to replicate. It's not possible to give the repo (public)? or recreate the repo setup without code?